# Can MvvmCross Messenger be used without IoC?

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross, eventaggregator

I would like to use MvvmCross Messenger to send messages between addins I'm developing for for an app whose source I cannot modify.

As such, I don't see a clear way to use IoC, so I would just roll my own singleton.

However my simple test gets an exception when I call Subscribe.

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var m = new MvxMessengerHub();
            // exception on Subscribe: 
            // The type initializer for 'MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger.MvxPluginLog' threw an exception.
            m.Subscribe<TestMessage>((msg) =>
            {
                Debug.Print("got msg");
            });
            m.Publish<TestMessage>(new TestMessage(this));
        }
    }
    public class TestMessage : MvxMessage
    {        
        public TestMessage(object sender): base(sender)
        {
        }
    }
```

Should [the doc](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/messenger?scroll=1216) say "can *only*" instead of "can"?

[image]

---

Here's the stack trace:

```
The type initializer for 'MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger.MvxPluginLog' threw an exception.
   at MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger.MvxPluginLog.get_Instance() in /_/MvvmCross.Plugins/Messenger/MvxPluginLog.cs:line 11
   at MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger.MvxMessengerHub.SubscribeInternal[TMessage](Action`1 deliveryAction, IMvxActionRunner actionRunner, MvxReference reference, String tag) in /_/MvvmCross.Plugins/Messenger/MvxMessengerHub.cs:line 75
   at MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger.MvxMessengerHub.Subscribe[TMessage](Action`1 deliveryAction, MvxReference reference, String tag) in /_/MvvmCross.Plugins/Messenger/MvxMessengerHub.cs:line 29
   at WpfApp1.MainWindow.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in D:\repos\esri\arcgis-pro-sdk-cim-viewer\WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 40
```

Update: I found [this](https://git.gloriumdev.com/mishchenko/MvvmCross-Plugins/-/blob/4.2.2/Messenger/MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.Test/MessengerHubTest.cs#L42) test from someone else's project from 5 yrs ago, so it seems like this must have worked in a previous version.

```cs
public void SubscribeAndPublishAllowsMessageToBeReceived()
{
    var messenger = new MvxMessengerHub();
    var message = new TestMessage(this);

    var messageReceived = false;
    messenger.Subscribe<TestMessage>(m =>
        {
            Assert.That(m, Is.EqualTo(message));
            Assert.That(m.Sender, Is.EqualTo(this));
            messageReceived = true;
        });

    messenger.Publish(message);

    Assert.IsTrue(messageReceived);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to inject it from the constructor or resolve dependency via `Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<T>` ?

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the exception thrown while calling Subscribe?

Comment: @TrevorBalcom done

Comment: @FabriBertani I'm not using IoC, is there a sample showing how to use MvvmCross in a class library that builds a dll which gets loaded as a plugin in an application which one has no control over?  In other words, I can't rebuild the exe - it belongs to someone else.  I can only extend it using their plugin framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/5354b207f2f626035a631b3762642ebdc3b48172/MvvmCross.Plugins/Messenger/MvxMessengerHub.cs#L77), you will see MvxMessengerHub references MvxPluginLog.Instance to write log messages. The exception is being thrown because `MvxPlugingLog.Instance.get` is being called internally by `MvxMessengerHub` at various points. [MvxPluginLog.Instance.get](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/5354b207f2f626035a631b3762642ebdc3b48172/MvvmCross.Plugins/Share/MvxPluginLog.cs#L11) is using MvvmCross IoC container to resolve IMvxLogProvider. You could provide your own implementation of IMvxMessengerHub that does not use MvxPluginLog.Instance.